# Initialize control in control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, controls

This is my custom control class:

```
// Extended ComboBox where ill change some property.
public class ExtComboBox : ComboBox
{
    ...
}

// ExtButton is a control that i am going to drop on Form from ToolBox.
public partial class ExtButton : Button
{
    public ExtComboBox ComboBoxInsideButton { get; set; }

    public ExtButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        ComboBoxInsideButton = new ExtComboBox();
        ComboBoxInsideButton.Text = "hi!";

        Controls.Add(ComboBoxInsideButton);
    }
}
```

Basically when i add this control to form there will be ComboBox on top off Button.
Don't ask my why i need this :D

Now if i need to change ComboBox text i simply use:

```
extButton1.ComboBoxInsideButton.Text = "aaa";
```

All work fine.. but :) when i am trying to change some ComboBox properties in Design mode (Window Properties -> Expand ComboBoxInsideButton -> Change Text to "bbb")
after rebuilding or running project ComboBox properties will be reseted (ExtButton.Designer.cs)

Question 1: How to initialize  subcontrol with some default properties value, so when ill drop control on Form all setting will be added?

and

Question 2: How to change properties of subcontrol on design time.

**EDIT:**
Answer here: [Designer does not generate code for a property of a subcontrol. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3701173)
Adding `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a mini-tut on how to create custom UserControls and accessing their members [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955642/controls-for-list-of-objects/11959225#11959225).  Pretty much, it looks like you are going to want add properties to your `ExtComboBox` that expose the `ComboBox` properties you'd like to change.  Then, in `ExtButton`, you will be able to use the `.` to change these values at runtime.

Also, instead of doing:

```
public ExtComboBox ComboBoxInsideButton { get; set; }
...
ComboBoxInsideButton = new ExtComboBox();
```

do

```
public ExtComboBox comboBoxInsideButton = null;
...
comboBoxInsideButton = new ExtComboBox();
```

Be sure to understand the difference between `private` and `public` also.  I'm not sure if you want your `ExtComboBox` to be `public` if you're placing it on another control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `public ExtComboBox ComboBoxInsideButton { get; set; }` is ok because i want to ExtCombox be public and can be edited by designer. I found the answer. Check my edit.